# systemd-logind[1439]: Failed to enable subscription: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, systemd-logind

I'm getting a black screen of death. The only way around it is booting upstart. VirtualBox, uninstalled guest additions.

Comment: Any followup on this? (Hopefully :-).)

Comment: It is fixed, I don't remember how. I must have been able to get to the grub screen to select an old kernel, and then installed guest additions cleanly (I had tried both from apt and virtualbox. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks! I think mine was a different issue, my instance booted up but accepted nether mouse nor keyboard input. Was solved by reinstalling lightdm with sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop from https://www.incredigeek.com/home/ubuntu-16-04-login-screen-issues/.

Comment: Actually fixing lightdm sounds more like what I did!